# Eclipse freezes while showing hover suggestions like method suggestions in class, method info etc

Tags: java, eclipse

When I enter a dot operator after entering the class name, Eclipse will show method suggestions auto complete, at that time Eclipse hangs and gets closed automatically.

It also happens when showing method info. Can someone help with this?

When I checked Eclipse log, I saw these exceptions

```
eclipse.buildId=4.13.0.I20190916-1045
java.version=1.8.0_312
java.vendor=Private Build
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.brainwy.liclipsetext.editor 4 0 2022-05-13 14:48:14.576
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.editor [93]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core; bundle-version="[2.3.0,2.3.1)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core; bundle-version="2.3.0.202104291051"
       org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core [94]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_ui
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_ui; bundle-version="2.3.0.202104291051"; singleton:="true"
       org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_ui [95]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core; bundle-version="[2.3.0,2.3.1)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core; bundle-version="2.3.0.202104291051"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core 4 0 2022-05-13 14:48:14.579
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core [94]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_ui 4 0 2022-05-13 14:48:14.580
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_ui [95]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core; bundle-version="[2.3.0,2.3.1)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core; bundle-version="2.3.0.202104291051"
       org.brainwy.liclipsetext.shared_core [94]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

Comment: The errors say that you have installed a plug-in which requires at least Java 11 but you are using Java 8 on Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) which is now 3 years and 10 releases old. Try running on the current Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23).

Comment: @greg-449 can you please let me know from where can I find and remove that plugin.

we have deployed only Java 8 in production, so I am using it for development.

Comment: You can still develop for Java 8 using the latest Eclipse even though Eclipse itself requires at least Java 11. Just tell Eclipse about the Java 8. Many of the current Eclipse downloads contain a suitable Java as part of the download.

Comment: okay thanks, it worked after uninstalling the plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @greg-449 for your comment.

> The errors say that you have installed a plug-in which requires at
> least Java 11 but you are using Java 8 on Eclipse 2019-09 (4.13) which
> is now 3 years and 10 releases old. Try running on the current Eclipse
> 2022-03 (4.23).

It resolved after uninstalling the plugin which requires at least Java 11